# Some issues in Swipe to delete for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture, android-database

Below is the code which i have used for deletion of item when swiping either left or right,now the problem is I'm putting an UNDO button in the snackbar.
When i swipe i delete the item from database,How to go about when UNDO is clicked?,because when UNDO is pressed the swipped item should come back.

```
  if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                //adapterr.removeItem(position);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(recyclerView, "1 Song deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                              /*  Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                snackbar1.show();*/

                            }
                        });

                snackbar.show();
                openDatabase();
                String whereClause = QueueDatabase.KEY_ID + " = " + queuee.get(position).getId();
                String[] whereArgs = null;
                db.delete(QueueDatabase.TABLE_QUEUE,whereClause,null);
                queuee.remove(position);
                adapterr.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                Toast.makeText(QueueActivity.this, "removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
               Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(recyclerView, "1 Song deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                              /*  Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                snackbar1.show();*/

                            }
                        });

                snackbar.show();
                openDatabase();
                String whereClause = QueueDatabase.KEY_ID + " = " + queuee.get(position).getId();
                String[] whereArgs = null;
                db.delete(QueueDatabase.TABLE_QUEUE,whereClause,null);
                queuee.remove(position);
                adapterr.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                Toast.makeText(QueueActivity.this, "removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

queuee is an array list which is used to collect all data from database,and later fill the recycler view. 
Please help,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take copy of deleted item & its position in other variable like

```
   int deletedPosition = position;
   YourItemType DeletedItem = YourList.get(position);
```

insert item in same position on click of undo

```
   YourList.add(deletedPosition, DeletedItem);
   YourAdapter.notifyItemInserted(deletedPosition);
```

I put this code in adapter.